# Update and Filter listpicker 

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have two list pickers with same databinding(from XML), When first listpicker have selection changed it should filter data of second listpicker and hide item which selected in first listpicker, same as second listpicker.

2 listpicker XAML...

```
<my:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        x:Name="listPicker1" Width="265" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18.667" Background="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="147,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FF1BA1E2" Height="35" SelectionChanged="listPicker1_SelectionChanged" >
                        <my:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Width="360" Height="34">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="item" Text="{Binding ChannelName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="18.667" Margin="12, 0, 2, 2" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </my:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    </my:ListPicker>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" Margin="52,5,0,5" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="91" Text="Channel 2 "/>
                    <my:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        x:Name="listPicker2" Width="265" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18.667" Background="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" Foreground="#FF1BA1E2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="147,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" SelectionChanged="listPicker2_SelectionChanged" >
                        <my:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Width="360" Height="34">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="item" Text="{Binding ChannelName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="18.667" Margin="12, 0, 2, 2" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </my:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    </my:ListPicker>
```

DataBinding with XML code

```
    public Customize()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("newsChannels.xml");

        var channels = from query in loadedData.Descendants("channel")
                       select new Channels
                       {
                           ChannelName = (string)query.Element("channelname"),
                       };
        listPicker1.ItemsSource = channels;
        listPicker2.ItemsSource = channels;
    }

    public class Channels
    {
        string channelname;

        public string ChannelName
        {
            get { return channelname; }
            set { channelname = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than databind the ListPickers to the exact same list try creating 2 proxy properties which control access to the underlying list. You could then have the getter for the proxy properties filter out whatever has been selected for the other list (assuming that the sleected object is also bound to the viewmodel. Alternatively (or possibly in addition) you could use the SelectionChanged event to force the updating to the proxy lists.

**Update** 
Here's an example:

Assuming a page contains this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="picker1" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding List1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            SelectionChanged="ListPicker1SelectionChanged" />
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="picker2"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding List2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionChanged="ListPicker2SelectionChanged" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The code behind should look like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new TwoListViewModel();
    }

    private void ListPicker1SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure that the selected Item is updated
        picker1.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();

        // rebind the other list
        var binding = picker2.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.ItemsSourceProperty).ParentBinding;
        picker2.SetBinding(ListPicker.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    }

    private void ListPicker2SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        picker2.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();

        var binding = picker1.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.ItemsSourceProperty).ParentBinding;
        picker1.SetBinding(ListPicker.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    }
}

public class TwoListViewModel
{
    public TwoListViewModel()
    {
        // MUST Initialize the selected items
        SelectedItem1 = "one";
        SelectedItem2 = "two";
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> InnerList
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
                   {
                       "one",
                       "two",
                       "three",
                       "four",
                       "five",
                   };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List1
    {
        get
        {
            return InnerList.Where(item => item != SelectedItem2);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List2
    {
        get
        {
            return InnerList.Where(item => item != SelectedItem1);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItem1 { get; set; }

    public string SelectedItem2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy for replying .. sorry but i m not a professional developer of WP7, i m new on WP7 app development, if u kindly help me out to write this code ..

Comment: Matt, another question i have to ask, is their any possibilities to set selected item as None ?, in listpicker it shows empty. I search on that but most of result i found they saying its not posible but they give one solution of it "collapsed"